# Socket.io Chat Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've created a chat server using javascript and nodejs. Everything seems to be working fine, but when I send the message, for the first message it displays it once, then for second message two times and so on.

I tried it on Linux, then on Windows machine and even on my iPad. It's showing the same result. I entered the counter also at the client side and the result are (for every message):
Message 1: 1
Message 2: 2
           1
Message 3: 3
           2
           1
Message 4: 4
           3
           2
           1

### Client

```
   send.addEventListener('click', event => {
       event.preventDefault();
       const msg = document.querySelector('#msg').value;
       document.querySelector('#msg').innerHTML = "";
       let packet = {
           username: userProfile.username,
           message: msg
       };
       let i = 0;
       socket.emit('chat', packet);
       socket.on('chat', (data) => {
       i=i+1;
       console.log(i);
       chatBox.innerHTML += `<p><strong>${data.username}:</strong> ${data.     message}</p>`;
       });
   });
});
```

### Server

```
   let stat = search(profile);
   if(stat.status === "failure")
   {   
       user.push(profile);
       io.sockets.emit('login', {status: "failure"});
   }
   else
   {
       io.sockets.emit('login', {status: "success"});
   }
 });

 let i = 0;
 socket.on('chat', data =>
 {
   i++;
   io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
   console.log(i);
 });
});
```

I was expecting the messages to be displayed on the chat Box. It's displaying the message but twice or thrice for every message.

Comment: every time you process a click, you are adding another `socket.on('chat',` listener - put the `socket.on('chat', (data)` code outside the `send.addEventListener('click', event => {` handler

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working now. Thanks very much......

Answer (score 0):

You are creating **socket listener** on every click event, that's why display count is increasing.